# pandoc-template markdown to pdf with latex no working

Tags: luatex, templates, pandoc, documentclass

I’m trying to create a minimal working pandoc template that would just take the `latex.cls` from the YAML metadata block in the `source.md` file.

So here is my template:

```
$if(documentclass)$
\documentclass{$documentclass$}
$endif$

$if(title)$
\title{$title$}
$endif$
$if(author)$
\author{$author$}
$endif$
\date{\today}

\begin{document}


$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$

$if(toc)$
\tableofcontents
$endif$

$body$

\end{document}
```

Here is the YAML metadata block

```
---
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: TMarticle
---
% How to Set Up a \LaTeX{} Distribution and Workstation
% Author

# Quick Introduction
```

and here’s the class that I am passing in the YAML metadata block:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{TMarticle}
\LoadClass{article} % we use a standard article as a base-class
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=4cm,top=4cm]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{listings} % for our code listings
\RequirePackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=green,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=true,hypertexnames=true}

% color definitions
\definecolor{TMgreen}{RGB}{14, 191, 48}
\definecolor{TMorange}{RGB}{243, 126, 25}
\definecolor{TMred}{RGB}{230, 6, 85}
\definecolor{TMcodeBackground}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\definecolor{TMcodeFrame}{RGB}{109, 108, 109}
\definecolor{TMtableHead}{RGB}{230, 6, 85}
\definecolor{TMtableRowTwo}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
\definecolor{TMtableRowOne}{RGB}{240, 240, 240}
\definecolor{TMemphasis}{RGB}{165, 32, 23}
\definecolor{TMwarning}{RGB}{250, 175, 52}
\definecolor{TMcritical}{RGB}{229, 0, 72}
\definecolor{TMnormal}{RGB}{54, 160, 220}
\definecolor{TMbulletinBackground}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\definecolor{TMtheorem}{RGB}{14, 191, 48}

% font settings
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[BoldFont=Source Code Pro]
\setmainfont{Lato Light}[
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]
\setsansfont{Lato Light}[
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Lato Light}[
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]

% Font for chapter number
\newfontfamily{\upperNumber}{Lato Light}[
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]

% we now start creating the TM-styled code listing environments
% the lstlisting environment is wrapped in an MD-frame
% first of all we need to define the mdframestyle that
% takes care of the background and the left bar

\mdfdefinestyle{TMstyleCode}{
            skipabove=4mm,
            skipbelow=0mm,
            %remove borders
            rightline=false,
            topline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=1mm,
            %margins
            innertopmargin=2mm,
            innerleftmargin=0mm,
            innerbottommargin=0mm,
            innerrightmargin=10pt,
            linecolor=TMcodeFrame,
            backgroundcolor=TMcodeBackground
}

\lstdefinestyle{TMstyle}{
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{TMgreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{TMorange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{TMred},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

% need to use inner commands to avoid the verbatim nature
% of listing environments!

\lstnewenvironment{TMcode}[3]
{
    \lstset{style=TMstyle, language=#1, caption=#2}
    \mdfsetup{style=TMstyleCode}
    \mdframed
    \hspace*{3mm}
    \minipage{0.75cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/home/louisvgn/texmf/tex/latex/images/code2.png}
    \endminipage
    \hspace*{1mm}
    \minipage{\textwidth-1.05cm}
        {\sffamily\Large #3}
    \endminipage
    \vspace*{-2mm}
}
{
    \endmdframed
}

% We now want to create the bulletin-environments
% we first define two new mdenvironments, one for the header and one for
% the content
\newmdenv[
        skipabove=4mm,
        skipbelow=1mm,
        innertopmargin=1mm,
        innerbottommargin=1mm,
        innerleftmargin=0mm,
        innerrightmargin=0pt,
        rightline=false,
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        linewidth=1mm,
        frametitlefont={\sffamily\bfseries},
        backgroundcolor=TMbulletinBackground]{TMbulletinBase}
\newmdenv[default, linewidth=0pt, backgroundcolor=TMbulletinBackground]{TMbulletinContent}

% we then define three styles, one for each type
\mdfdefinestyle{normal}{linecolor=TMnormal}
\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{linecolor=TMwarning}
\mdfdefinestyle{critical}{linecolor=TMcritical}

% we then define some auxilliary commands
\newcommand{\@TMbulletinTitleContent}[2]
{
    \hspace*{2mm}\begin{minipage}{0.75cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{1mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1.05cm}
            #2
    \end{minipage}
}

% and finally the main environment
% takes type (warning/normal/critical) as first argument
% takes bulletin title as second argument
\newenvironment{TMbulletin}[2]{
    \begin{TMbulletinBase}[style=#1, frametitle=\@TMbulletinTitleContent{/home/louisvgn/texmf/tex/latex/images/#1.png}{#2}]
    \vspace*{1mm}
    \begin{TMbulletinContent}
}
{
    \end{TMbulletinContent}
    \end{TMbulletinBase}
}

% we now define the mdtable styles
\newcommand{\tableCaption}{}
\mdfdefinestyle{TMstyleTable}{
            skipabove=4mm,
            skipbelow=0mm,
            %remove borders
            rightline=false,
            topline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=1mm,
            %margins
            innertopmargin=0mm,
            innerleftmargin=0mm,
            innerbottommargin=0mm,
            innerrightmargin=0pt,
            backgroundcolor=TMcodeBackground,
            linecolor=TMtableHead,
}
\everyrow{\tabucline[.4mm white]{}}
\tabulinesep=^3mm_2mm
\taburowcolors[2] 2{TMtableRowOne .. TMtableRowTwo}
\newenvironment{TMtable}[3]
{
    \renewcommand{\tableCaption}{#3}
    \begin{table}[#2]
    \begin{mdframed}[style=TMstyleTable]
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth{#1}
        \rowfont{\bfseries\sffamily\leavevmode\color{white}}
        \rowcolor{TMtableHead!}
}
{
    \end{tabu}
    \end{mdframed}
    \caption{\tableCaption}
    \end{table}
}

% theorem styles
\declaretheoremstyle[
    postheadspace=\newline,
    headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    mdframed={
            skipabove=4mm,
            skipbelow=0mm,
            rightline=false,
            topline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=1mm,
            linecolor=TMtheorem,
            backgroundcolor=TMcodeBackground,
    }
]{TMtheoremStyle}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, within=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, sibling=theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, sibling=theorem]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, sibling=theorem]{proposition}
```

This is what I get as error message with the command:

```
$ pandoc --template=try.template --pdf-engine=lualatex -o output.pdf source.md
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \hypertarget
```

Comment: `%` does not comment out lines in markdown.

Comment: I know, `%` is markup for pandoc markdown which create title/author/date

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML metadata block is in `rmarkdown` format. For plain `pandoc` it has to look like this:

```
---
documentclass: TMarticle
---
```

Comment: Indeed, it does not give me the error message anymore, but I still get error message `Error producing PDF. ! Undefined control sequence. l.126 \tightlist` with that template while I do not get the error with `default.latex` template from pandoc. I don’t get where that comes from.

Comment: Pandoc defines `\tightlist` in the default template. You have to copy the definition to your template or define your own